# How to got Session working in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

In Laravel 5.8 session is not working.

.env setting:
`SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Controller file `index()` function :

`$request->session()->put('prediction','xyz');`

I first set session and then try to get it to other function `show()` in the controller.

`echo $request->session()->get('prediction');exit;`

But that is not working it got blank.

**Kernel.php**

```php
<?php

 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Are you logged into a session? and check the storage dir has write permissions

Comment: I am using window 10, There is all permissions for every one

Comment: Check the permissions of the folder `storage/framework/sessions`. Since you are using the file driver, see if laravel can and is creating a session file at the above location (of course, unless you haven't changed the session file location.)

Answer (score 0):

From what you're explaining, the issue seems to reside with the `$request`. You don't seem to be using any dependency injection. So at the top of the file, you can add the `Request` use statement (`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`) and in the parameters of the `index` function, you can pass through `Request $request`. So the full thing would look like `public function index(Request $request)`.

If you have used the dependency injection and it still doesn't work, try removing the `$request` variable. So the result would be `session()->put('someKey', 'SomeValue');`

Answer (score 0):

don't know why its not working sometimes in Laravel 5.8 but there is solution how it works for me in similar situation

```
<?php
    session()->put('login_user' , $user);
    session()->save();
```

issue occurs when your SESSION_DRIVER=file in .env file and session file is not updating accordingly.